# ExtJs drop and replace current panel with dragged panel

Tags: extjs

i have a panel setup like this(each number represents a panel):

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

what i want to do is for example, i drag panel 1 over panel 6 and panel 1 should be at panel 6 and 6 should be at 1, like:

```
6 2
3 4
5 1
7 8
```

How can i do this ? :O

Ty in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [Sencha Portal](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html) feature with some modifications below to achieve this.

My source code extended the portal example in latest version (4.0.7) as the following:

1. portal.html

```html
<html>
<head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portal.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../builds/ext-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <!-- shared example code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script>
    <!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="classes.js"></script> 
     -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="portal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
        Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.app', 'classes');

        Ext.require([
            'Ext.layout.container.*',
            'Ext.resizer.Splitter',
            'Ext.fx.target.Element',
            'Ext.fx.target.Component',
            'Ext.window.Window',
            'Ext.app.Portlet',
            'Ext.app.PortalColumn',
            'Ext.app.PortalPanel',
            'Ext.app.Portlet',
            'Ext.app.PortalDropZone',
            'Ext.app.GridPortlet',
            'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'
        ]);

        Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.create('Ext.app.Portal');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="app-msg" style="display:none;"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

1. portal.js

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel', 'Ext.app.PortalColumn', 'Ext.app.GridPortlet', 'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'],

    getTools: function(){
        return [{
            xtype: 'tool',
            type: 'gear',
            handler: function(e, target, panelHeader, tool){
                var portlet = panelHeader.ownerCt;
                portlet.setLoading('Working...');
                Ext.defer(function() {
                    portlet.setLoading(false);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }];
    },

    initComponent: function(){
        var content = '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.example.shortBogusMarkup+'</div>';

        Ext.apply(this, {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5' // pad the layout from the window edges
            },
            items: [{
                id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'box',
                region: 'north',
                height: 40,
                html: 'Ext Portal'
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    id: 'app-options',
                    title: 'Options',
                    region: 'west',
                    animCollapse: true,
                    width: 200,
                    minWidth: 150,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    split: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    layoutConfig:{
                        animate: true
                    },
                    items: [{
                        html: content,
                        title:'Navigation',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        border: false,
                        iconCls: 'nav'
                    },{
                        title:'Settings',
                        html: content,
                        border: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        iconCls: 'settings'
                    }]
                },{
                    id: 'app-portal',
                    xtype: 'portalpanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'col-1',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-1',
                            title: 'Grid Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.GridPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        },{
                            id: 'portlet-2',
                            title: 'Portlet 2',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-2',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-3',
                            title: 'Portlet 3',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.example.bogusMarkup+'</div>',
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        },{
                            id: 'portlet-4',
                            title: 'Stock Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.ChartPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
        this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
    },

    showMsg: function(msg) {
        var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
            msgId = Ext.id();

        this.msgId = msgId;
        el.update(msg).show();

        Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
    },

    clearMsg: function(msgId) {
        if (msgId === this.msgId) {
            Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
        }
    }
   });
```

1. PortalDropZone.js

```
    Ext.define('Ext.app.PortalDropZone', {
    extend: 'Ext.dd.DropTarget',

    constructor: function(portal, cfg) {
        this.portal = portal;
        Ext.dd.ScrollManager.register(portal.body);
        Ext.app.PortalDropZone.superclass.constructor.call(this, portal.body, cfg);
        portal.body.ddScrollConfig = this.ddScrollConfig;
    },

    ddScrollConfig: {
        vthresh: 50,
        hthresh: -1,
        animate: true,
        increment: 200
    },

    createEvent: function(dd, e, data, col, c, pos) {
        return {
            portal: this.portal,
            panel: data.panel,
            columnIndex: col,
            column: c,
            position: pos,
            data: data,
            source: dd,
            rawEvent: e,
            status: this.dropAllowed
        };
    },

    notifyOver: function(dd, e, data) {
        var xy = e.getXY(),
            portal = this.portal,
            proxy = dd.proxy;

        // case column widths
        if (!this.grid) {
            this.grid = this.getGrid();
        }

        // handle case scroll where scrollbars appear during drag
        var cw = portal.body.dom.clientWidth;
        if (!this.lastCW) {
            // set initial client width
            this.lastCW = cw;
        } else if (this.lastCW != cw) {
            // client width has changed, so refresh layout & grid calcs
            this.lastCW = cw;
            //portal.doLayout();
            this.grid = this.getGrid();
        }

        // determine column
        var colIndex = 0,
            colRight = 0,
            cols = this.grid.columnX,
            len = cols.length,
            cmatch = false;

        for (len; colIndex < len; colIndex++) {
            colRight = cols[colIndex].x + cols[colIndex].w;
            if (xy[0] < colRight) {
                cmatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // no match, fix last index
        if (!cmatch) {
            colIndex--;
        }

        // find insert position
        var overPortlet, pos = 0,
            h = 0,
            match = false,
            overColumn = portal.items.getAt(colIndex),
            portlets = overColumn.items.items,
            overSelf = false;

        len = portlets.length;

        for (len; pos < len; pos++) {
            overPortlet = portlets[pos];
            h = overPortlet.el.getHeight();
            if (h === 0) {
                overSelf = true;
            } else if ((overPortlet.el.getY() + (h / 2)) > xy[1]) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        pos = (match && overPortlet ? pos : overColumn.items.getCount()) + (overSelf ? -1 : 0);
        var overEvent = this.createEvent(dd, e, data, colIndex, overColumn, pos);

        if (portal.fireEvent('validatedrop', overEvent) !== false && portal.fireEvent('beforedragover', overEvent) !== false) {

            // make sure proxy width is fluid in different width columns
            proxy.getProxy().setWidth('auto');

            if (overPortlet) {
                proxy.moveProxy(overPortlet.el.dom.parentNode, match ? overPortlet.el.dom : null);
            } else {
                proxy.moveProxy(overColumn.el.dom, null);
            }

            this.lastPos = {
                c: overColumn,
                col: colIndex,
                p: overSelf || (match && overPortlet) ? pos : false
            };
            this.scrollPos = portal.body.getScroll();

            portal.fireEvent('dragover', overEvent);
            return overEvent.status;
        } else {
            return overEvent.status;
        }

    },

    notifyOut: function() {
        delete this.grid;
    },

    notifyDrop: function(dd, e, data) {
        delete this.grid;
        if (!this.lastPos) {
            return;
        }
        var c = this.lastPos.c,
            col = this.lastPos.col,
            pos = this.lastPos.p,
            panel = dd.panel,
            dropEvent = this.createEvent(dd, e, data, col, c, pos !== false ? pos : c.items.getCount());

        if (this.portal.fireEvent('validatedrop', dropEvent) !== false && this.portal.fireEvent('beforedrop', dropEvent) !== false) {

            // make sure panel is visible prior to inserting so that the layout doesn't ignore it
            panel.el.dom.style.display = '';
            /*
             * Start customization
             * Switch position of two panels when drop
             */
            var sourceColumn = panel.ownerCt;
            var sourceRow = sourceColumn.items.indexOf(panel);
            if (pos !== false) {
                var targetPanel = c.items.getAt(pos);
                sourceColumn.insert(sourceRow, targetPanel);
                c.insert(pos, panel);
            } else {
                c.add(panel);
            }
            /*
             * End of customization
             */
            dd.proxy.hide();
            this.portal.fireEvent('drop', dropEvent);

            // scroll position is lost on drop, fix it
            var st = this.scrollPos.top;
            if (st) {
                var d = this.portal.body.dom;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    d.scrollTop = st;
                },
                10);
            }

        }
        delete this.lastPos;
        return true;
    },

    // internal cache of body and column coords
    getGrid: function() {
        var box = this.portal.body.getBox();
        box.columnX = [];
        this.portal.items.each(function(c) {
            box.columnX.push({
                x: c.el.getX(),
                w: c.el.getWidth()
            });
        });
        return box;
    },

    // unregister the dropzone from ScrollManager
    unreg: function() {
        Ext.dd.ScrollManager.unregister(this.portal.body);
        Ext.app.PortalDropZone.superclass.unreg.call(this);
    }
    });
```